# How do I hook up a water line to the ice-maker on my old Frigidaire fridge?

Tags: water, appliances, refrigerator, valve, ice-maker

I am trying to hook up the ice maker for an old Frigidaire fridge, but there is no line running out of the back. When I opened the access panel I found the water valve but unlike newer water valves there is a screw on port that is about an inch wide. Does anyone know what to do?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you'll need an adapter to convert this back to 1/4" compression. Guessing someone took off one piece too many when the water line was previously disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a 90 FPT (female pipe thread) by compression fitting (or build an equivalent from an elbow and a compression adapter), since it looks kinda cramped right there:

[image: FPT 90 by compression]

Then some 3/8" or 1/4" flexible copper or poly tubing to hook it in (1/4" is most commonly used with fridges).

Don't use a saddle valve: they are terrible (eg: [What can I do about a saddle valve that won't turn on?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53980)). Instead, hook it into the source water with a tee and another compression fitting. You'll also need a valve: there are valves that have a compression fitting on one side, and sweat, pex, FPT, MPT, etc on the other; or you can go for a compression x compression valve that can go anywhere inline on the flex tubing):

[image: sweat x compression ball valve]
[image: compression x compression fitting ball valve]

Which is best depends on the layout and accessibility. It can be pretty handy to have a shut-off valve behind the fridge, so in case something leaks/breaks you don't have to run to the basement to hunt for a valve somewhere, but at the same time, I wouldn't personally hook up a line using a compression fitting without a valve immediately upstream. Nothing is wrong with two valves of course (other than cost).